# Solr : eDismax does not always use the defaultOperator "AND"

Tags: solr, operators, default, edismax

I set the defaultOperator at "AND" in schema.xml :
`<solrQueryParser defaultOperator="AND"/>`

I use the defType=eDismax in my query. It works very well, but when I want to use "AND" or "OR" operators, it doesn't use "AND" as the default operator for the blanks I left without operators.

Examples:

**field1:a field2:b** does the same thing than **field1:a AND field2:b** : OK

**field1:a OR field2:b** : OK, I have all the results that I want

but

**field1:a (field2:b OR field2:c)** does the same thing than **field1:a OR (field2:b OR field2:c)** : that's not OK

How can I force him to use "AND" as the default operator even in that case ?

Answer (score 0):

This, unfortunately, is a [known issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2649). You have two solutions:

1. Fix it upstream (probably really hard)
2. Fix your user's queries as they come in (probably prone to errors)

I'm running into this too. Looks like no easy solutions in site atm. You could go vote on the bug...not sure that does much though.